# How to enable Eclipse debugging features in a web application?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I am using Django framework for my Python Web Application using Eclipse IDE and PyDev Plugin.
How can I use the debugging features?

**UPDATES1**
particularly using http://pydev.org/updates plugin

**UPDATES2**
I already did the following:

**.pydevproject**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?eclipse-pydev version="1.0"?>

<pydev_project>
<pydev_property name="org.python.pydev.PYTHON_PROJECT_INTERPRETER">Python25
</pydev_property>
<pydev_property name="org.python.pydev.PYTHON_PROJECT_VERSION">python 2.5
</pydev_property>
<pydev_pathproperty name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_SOURCE_PATH">
<path>/pi-proto</path>
</pydev_pathproperty>
<pydev_pathproperty name="org.python.pydev.PROJECT_EXTERNAL_SOURCE_PATH">
<path>C:\Program Files\GeoDjango\Django-1.0.2-final</path>
<path>C:\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_2.2.3.2011100616\pysrc
</path>
</pydev_pathproperty>
</pydev_project>
```

**manage.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management import execute_manager
try:
    import settings # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.)\n" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        command = sys.argv[1]

    if settings.DEBUG and (command == "runserver" or command == "testserver"):

        # Make pydev debugger works for auto reload.
        try:
            import pydevd
        except ImportError:
            sys.stderr.write("Error: " +
                "You must add org.python.pydev.debug.pysrc to your PYTHONPATH.")
            sys.exit(1)

        from django.utils import autoreload
        m = autoreload.main
        def main(main_func, args=None, kwargs=None):
            import os
            if os.environ.get("RUN_MAIN") == "true":
                def pydevdDecorator(func):
                    def wrap(*args, **kws):
                        pydevd.settrace(suspend=False)
                        return func(*args, **kws)
                    return wrap
                main_func = pydevdDecorator(main_func)

            return m(main_func, args, kwargs)

        autoreload.main = main

    execute_manager(settings)
```

**Run Configurations - Arguments**

```
runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

**UPDATES3**
I am following this link http://bear330.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/how-to-debug-django-web-application-with-autoreload/

But no success. Would you guide me on how to correctly follow the above link..Then I will update the result here.

**UPDATES4** 
I am using Python 2.5.2, GeoDjango 1.2.7, Eclipse Indigo with PyDev Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some how-tos:

- http://matt.geek.nz/2009/02/debugging-django-apps-with-eclipse-and-pydev/
- [Django debugging with Eclipse and PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527934/django-debugging-with-eclipse-and-pydev)
- http://brill.no/debugging-django-apps-with-eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

To configure PyDev to work with Django see: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_django.html

So, if you execute without the auto-reload feature (which PyDev will do automatically when you create a new Django run), you can do all directly (i.e.: the debugger and launching don't need any special adjustments).

Now, if you want to have auto-reload on while developing, use the tips at: [PyDev and Django: how to restart dev server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746512/pydev-and-django-how-to-restart-dev-server/7648375#7648375) (to overcome an issue where Django will leave child processes alive when the main process is killed)

And see the session related to the remote debugger at: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html to see how to attach the debugger to PyDev when using the auto-reload feature (mainly, you'll need to start the remote debugger, but will add breakpoints regularly and PyDev will stop on those provided you call pydevd.patch_django_autoreload() before you main session).

Comment: That was very helpful but I can't follow it with success. Would you guide me by updating the above code or tell me what to do...

Comment: Before the `if __name__ == "__main__":`, add `import pydevd;pydevd.patch_django_autoreload()` and in the autoreload.py, apply the patch from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746512/pydev-and-django-how-to-restart-dev-server/7648375#7648375

Comment: I am using GeoDjango 1.2.7 and Python 2.5.2. Any version specifics to apply the patch?